# How to properly set up BackgroundWorker in WPF VB

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I am working in VB and when the end user clicks on a button, I want to show a “Please wait” window (no progress update necessary) and trigger the process in the background on another thread as it might take a while to complete.  I understand BackgroundWorker is the recommended approach for this, and although I have previously set up a BGW on a windows forms application, I am new to WPF and having a hard time understanding the differences.

In order to reuse some of my code, I have written a function (“DbOperation”) that executes a SQL stored procedure (from parameter) and returns a data table (or NULL if no output), and it seems to work well everywhere except in concert with my BGW.

I understand UI should only be affected by the main thread, and background threads should not touch the UI, and the BGW thread should call the long-running process.

```
Private Sub btnProcessReports_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnProcessReports.Click

    'Set up background worker
    bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = False
    bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = False
    AddHandler bgw.DoWork, AddressOf bgw_DoWork
    AddHandler bgw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bgw_RunWorkerCompleted

    'Show please wait window
    f.Label1.Text = "Importing web reports. Please wait."
    f.Show()

    'Start the work!
    bgw.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    'Set current thread as STA
    Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)

    'Trigger job
    Dim Qry As String = "EXEC [msdb].[dbo].sp_start_job N'Import Online Payment Portal Reports';"
    DbOperation(Qry)

End Sub

Public Function DbOperation(ByVal qry As String, Optional ByVal type As DatabaseQueryReturnType = DatabaseQueryReturnType.NonQuery) As Object

    Dim objDB As New Object
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter

    OpenConnection()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(qry)
    cmd.Connection = con

    If type = DatabaseQueryReturnType.DataTable Then
        dt = New DataTable
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

        Try
            da.Fill(dt)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error retrieving data from database: " & ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try

        objDB = dt
        dt.Dispose()
        CloseConnection()
        Return objDB

    ElseIf type = DatabaseQueryReturnType.NonQuery Then
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error executing nonquery: " & ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try

        objDB = Nothing
        CloseConnection()
        Return objDB

    End If

    Return objDB

End Function
```

When I try running the program, it gives me “The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.” on the line that calls my function.  After a bit of research, I learned that you have to call SetApartmentState() before the thread is started, but this doesn’t make sense since the recommended code seems to be:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
```

After adding this line, I then get “Failed to set the specified COM apartment state” on that line of code. 
I have also tried commenting out the messagebox lines in the function in case it was trying to open the messageboxes on the UI thread, but it had no impact and I still got the same errors. 
What am I missing in my code to get the function to run on the BGW thread?

Comment: `OpenConnection()` doesn't return anything, so you have declared you connection object somewhere else. Never do that. Create the connection in-place and dispose of it and all the other objects you create when you're done with them. Possibly, with `Using` statements. The same for your `DbOperation() method`. You return an `Object` (`objDB`), but `DbOperation(Qry)` doesn't assign it This is not the way to use a Function. Don't do that. If you need to pass values (not UI objects references) to the BGW's thread from the UI Thread, use the `RunWorkerAsync(Object)` overload.

Comment: `I understand BackgroundWorker is the recommended approach` Not anymore. You really should look into `Async/Await`. You'll end up with less code, cleaner code, easier maintenance down the road.

Comment: If all you are going to do is to ask the user to wait, why are you using threads at all?

Comment: You are passing the query as a string. Any query that has parameters should be parameterized. It is not possible to pass this as a string alone.

Comment: @InteXX Thank you very much!  This is very helpful, and I will research this approach.  I am self-taught and just trying to make it through with the help of the community to the best of my ability.  It is very much appreciated!